# Feathers (Starling): Color each line or letter individually

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, colors

Is it possible to color each line or each letter individually in a TextArea or TextInput?

Maybe by using a shader if that is even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured out that I can use HTML in the textFields, so I use HTML tags to convert [red] to <font color="#FF0000">

Answer (score 0):

convert the letter/s you want to chnge on symbol and set them a name, then from the code or creating an interpolation in the timeline you should be able to manipulate the color and all the properties